# Profiler for Qt Creator + msvc compiler

Tags: qt, visual-c++, profiler

How to profile a Qt program using Qt creator with msvc compiler?

Answer (score 7):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no integrated equivalent to **valgrind** in QtCreator for Windows.

On the other hand, you can use a stand-alone application like [**very sleepy**](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy), which supports any native Windows app. It just attaches to a running process and lets you analyze the captured data through the functions of the process. It has been useful to me for finding performance bottlenecks in QtCreator applications that needed to be compiled with MSVC.